# Grunt grunt-contrib-jasmine

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have recently started to use grunt for JS project.

I have got a plugin called 'grunt-contrib-jasmine' that I'm using for Jasmine testing. I works great but I'm not able to run tests by specrunner in browser. Can I achieve this by using this plugin or do I need to install something else.

Also when a plugin is not required anymore, is it best to just comment it out or is there any command to uninstall, eg: `npm uninstall grunt-contrib-jasmine --save-dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*grunt-contrib-jasmine* is only for headless browser (phantomjs) so I afraid you will not be able to run this in browser. You will need to set up that manually.

In order to uninstall a plugin, use the command you mentioned:

It will remove the entry from package.json and it'll also uninstall the package too.

Answer (score 4):

Just for clarification, you *can* load the `_SpecRunner.html` file manually in the browser, but the grunt plugin will only run the tests in PhantomJS.

You can specify the `keepRunner:true` option in your gruntfile to keep the `_SpecRunner.html` file around after the tests run.

Then you can start a static web server ([grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect), and [node-static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static) both work fine for me) to the root of your project, and you should be able to manually open that `_SpecRunner.html` in a browser and run your tests there.

EDIT: I ended up giving [Testem](https://github.com/airportyh/testem) a try, which can launch your tests in PhantomJS *and* real browsers. It's still early, but I think I'll be setting aside grunt-contrib-jasmine in favor of [Testem](https://github.com/airportyh/testem) and [grunt-contrib-testem](https://github.com/inossidabile/grunt-contrib-testem).